# Metodo stop()/start() no funciona

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Tengo un problema con el botón de parada. Cuando pulso el botón de parada este llama al método stop() del objeto MediaPlayer. Pero después cuando quiero seguir la reproducción desde 0, pulsando el botón play, el archivo no se reproduce. Y por otro lado debo sobreescribir el método onDestroy() para liberar cuando cambio de actividad, pero esto hace que se me pare la app y sin embargo si el mismo código que utilizo en onDestroy() lo inserto en el método onStop() este me funciona bien. Porqué?.
Gracias.
Este es mi código:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer reproductor = new MediaPlayer();
    private Button botonReproducir;
    private Button botonParar;
    private Button botonPausar;
    private Button botonAvanzar10;
    private Button botonRetroceder10;
    private Bundle guardarEstado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      
        guardarEstado = new Bundle();
     
        botonReproducir = findViewById(R.id.botonReproducir);
        botonParar = findViewById(R.id.botonParar);
        botonPausar = findViewById(R.id.botonPausar);
        botonAvanzar10 = findViewById(R.id.botonAvanzar10);
        botonRetroceder10 = findViewById(R.id.botonRetroceder10);
   
        botonReproducir.setOnClickListener(this);
        botonParar.setOnClickListener(this);
        botonPausar.setOnClickListener(this);
        botonAvanzar10.setOnClickListener(this);
        botonRetroceder10.setOnClickListener(this);
     
        reproductor=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio);
    }
     public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume();
        reproductor.seekTo(guardarEstado.getInt("posicion"));
        reproductor.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (reproductor != null) {
            try {
                reproductor.stop();
                reproductor.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == botonReproducir) {
            if (reproductor == null) {
               reproductor.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       reproductor.start();
                   }
               });
            } else {
             onResume(guardarEstado);
            }
        }
        if (v == botonParar) {
            if (reproductor != null) {
                guardarEstado.putInt("posicion", 0);
                reproductor.stop();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy importante saber que usar que **si usas `.release()`, se elimina la referencia del media player y esta ya no existira**, por lo tanto si deseas cambiar únicamente de Activity y deseas tratar de mantener la instancia se sugiero únicamente usar .stop() en este caso:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (reproductor != null) {
        try {
            reproductor.stop();
           // reproductor.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

cuando regresas a la Activity se llama el método `onCreate()` aquí te sugiero revisar si la instancia de `MediaPlayer` existe

```
  public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume();

        if(reproductor!=null && !reproductor.isPlaying()){
           reproductor.seekTo(guardarEstado.getInt("posicion"));
           reproductor.start();   
        }else{
          //No existe instancia activa.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, Jorgesys. Tengo 2 problemas. El primero es que necesito parar el reproductor y cuando lo vuelvo a reproducir, debe comenzar de 0. Y usando el método stop(), no lo hace. Y el segundo es que cuando cambio de activity mediante un item debo invocar a onDestroy() y liberar recursos. Pero solo lo consigo invocando a onStop().

Comment: Si lo necesitas reproducir desde 0 realiza:  reproductor.seekTo(0); y luego llama: reproductor.start();

Comment: Ya si así se que lo puedo hacer, pero el problema al que me enfrento es que no me dejan utilizar el método seekTo() para ponerlo a 0 al clicar en el botón parar, es una de las condiciones de la tarea. Por eso invoco a stop(), pero al hacerlo y hacer clic en reproducir, no se reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he conseguido reiniciar la reproducción desde un botón sin recurrir al método **seekTo()**.
Lo que hago es que cuando hago clic en el botón "parar" invoco al método **seekTo()** y le paso como parámetro **getDuration()**, luego implemento un oyente **setOnCompletionListener()** y dentro invoco al método **pause()**. Entonces cuando hago clic en el botón "reproducir", donde he actualizado el método **setLooping()** a **true**, se encuentra con el reproductor en el inicio.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        
        if (v == botonReproducir) {
            if (reproductor == null) {
               reproductor.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       reproductor.start();

                   }
               });
            } else {
             onResume(guardarEstado);
            }
        }
        
        if (v == botonParar) {
            if (reproductor != null) {
                guardarEstado.putInt("posicion", 0);
                reproductor.seekTo(reproductor.getDuration());
                reproductor.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        reproductor.pause();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
  public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume();
        if(reproductor!=null&&guardarEstado!=null) {
            if (guardarEstado.getInt("posicion") != 0) {
                reproductor.seekTo(guardarEstado.getInt("posicion"));
                reproductor.start();
            } else {
                reproductor.start();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "El objeto MediaPlayer es nulo o el Bundle guardarEstado no existe",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```